# How to specify multiple buildtypes in devenv tasks, CruiseControl.net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, devenv

I want to do Clean and Build in devenv. I just noticed that buildtype flag can have only one item (Clean;Build not allowed). Do you have any idea how to specify multiple BuildTypes?

```
<tasks>
  <devenv>
    <solutionfile>C:\Source\Developer.sln</solutionfile>
    <configuration>Release</configuration>
    <buildtype>Build</buildtype> // How to do Clean and build here???
    <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com</executable>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>900</buildTimeoutSeconds>
  </devenv>
</tasks>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two tasks.  Each `<devenv>` block corresponds to one `devenv.com` invocation.  The options to `devenv.com` only allow you to `/Clean` or `/Rebuild` instead of building.  If you want to clean first and then build normally you will need to invoke `devenv.com` twice and therefore you need two tasks.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way around this, which is to invoke an MSBUILD task against a project file; this in turn calls devenv against the solution file; advantage to this is it makes it easier to integrate thinks like unit test, code analysis etc.

Here's a couple of targets from my Common.Targets

```
<Target Name="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(BuildFolder)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(BuildFolder)" Condition="!Exists('$(BuildFolder)')" />

    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionName).sln" Properties="ReferencePath=$(ReferencePath);Configuration=$(Configuration)" Targets="Clean" />
</Target>

<Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Version">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SolutionName).sln" Properties="ReferencePath=$(ReferencePath);Configuration=$(Configuration);OutputPath=$(OutputPath);OutDir=$(OutputPath)\;DeployDir=$(CodeDeployFolder)\;Deploy=true;BuildConstants=$(BuildConstants)" />
</Target>
```

Then for the CruiseControl task I have

```
    <msbuild>
        <executable>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>code</workingDirectory>
        <projectFile>Mailer.proj</projectFile>
        <targets>BuildAll;DistributeLibrary</targets>
        <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
    </msbuild>
```

This also makes it easier to add new processes across your build farm, e.g. say you want to introduce StyleCop analysis into your project, you don't have to change the CC.NET settings just introduce/extend a CodeAnalysis target and make that part of BuildAll